# Spark Parse Text File to DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Currently, I can parse a text file to a Spark DataFrame by way of the RDD API with the following code:

```
def row_parse_function(raw_string_input):
    # Do parse logic...
    return pyspark.sql.Row(...)

raw_rdd = spark_context.textFile(full_source_path)
# Convert RDD of strings to RDD of pyspark.sql.Row
row_rdd = raw_rdd.map(row_parse_function).filter(bool)
# Convert RDD of pyspark.sql.Row to Spark DataFrame.
data_frame = spark_sql_context.createDataFrame(row_rdd, schema)
```

Is this current approach ideal?

Or is there a better way to do this without using the older RDD API.

FYI, Spark 2.0.

Comment: My data isn't csv formatted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clay,

This is a good approach to load a file that has not specific format instead CSV, JSON, ORC, Parquet or from Database.

If you have any kind of specific logic to work on it, this is the best way to do that. Using RDD is for this kind of situation, when you need to run a specific logic in your data that is not trivial.

You can read [here](https://databricks.com/blog/2016/07/14/a-tale-of-three-apache-spark-apis-rdds-dataframes-and-datasets.html) about the uses of the APIs of Spark. And you are in the situation of RDD is the best approach.